# How to use EEGLAB "pop_loadset" with Oct2py

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, octave, eeglab

I'm trying to work on a eeg file which is in .mat format. And I need to convert it to a eeglab format, `pop_loadset` is supposed to do that. But it's not working.

I can read the file using `scipy.io.loadmat()`. But I don't know how to work with that format. I'm working on google colab.

```
matItem ='/content/drive/MyDrive/Depression Rest/Matlab Files/507_Depression_REST.mat'
matData = octave.pop_loadset(matItem)

#matData = scipy.io.loadmat(matItem)
```

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Oct2PyError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-88-79de92d55448> in <cell line: 2>()
      1 matItem ='/content/drive/MyDrive/Depression Rest/Matlab Files/507_Depression_REST.mat'
----> 2 matData = octave.pop_loadset(matItem)
      3 
      4 #matData = scipy.io.loadmat(matItem)

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/oct2py/core.py in _exist(self, name)
    755             if "error:" in resp:
    756                 msg = 'Value "%s" does not exist in Octave workspace'
--> 757                 raise Oct2PyError(msg % name)
    758             else:
    759                 exist = 2

Oct2PyError: Value "pop_loadset" does not exist in Octave workspace`
```

I've tried using `loadmat` then convert by using mne Python. But it's not working. I'm using this dataset:
[pred+ct](https://unmm-my.sharepoint.com/personal/jcavanagh_unm_edu/_layouts/15/onedrive.aspx?id=%2Fpersonal%2Fjcavanagh%5Funm%5Fedu%2FDocuments%2FDepression%20Rest&ga=1)

Answer (score 2):

This tutorial demonstrates how to use EEGLAB functions from Python: https://eeglab.org/others/EEGLAB_and_python.html#how-to-call-eeglab-functions-from-python

You are already using Oct2py, so you need to add the desired functions to Python using `octave.addpath`.

It looks like you should be using

```py
octave.addpath('/data/matlab/eeglab/functions/popfunc')
```

Comment: It works thanks! But now it's giving new error

Octave evaluation error:
error: 'finputcheck' undefined near line 93 column 5
error: called from:
    pop_loadset at line 93, column 3